# How to show the full file path in PHPStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

I'm new to PhpStorm and wondered if it's possible to show the full file path for an open file without hovering the mouse over the file tab?

I can only find this; http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/navigating-to-file-path.html

In Eclipse based IDEs the current open file path appears in the title bar.

Comment: It appears in IDE title bar as well (Windows OS for sure, but unlikely for Mac). In any case -- **Navigate | File Path** does the job for currently opened file in Editor (or selected in Project View panel)

Comment: Yeah, Im on a Mac and **Navigate | File Path** doesn't appear

Comment: This is how `File Path` popup looks like: http://postimg.org/image/3ywuaycgf/ . You have to check from where you invoke it (where focus is) -- if from Project View then look there -- sometimes it's a bit hard to notice it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Solution

There is now an option to do this in the editor settings labeled "Always show full path in window header"

*Settings/Preferences | Appearance and Behavior | Appearance | UI Options*

[image]

## Documentation

**Always show full path in window header**

> Show the full path to the project and to the current file in the main
> window header. When disabled, the header will show only the name of
> the project and file.

Reference: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-appearance.html#ui

*Note: Another useful setting for those looking for visibility of file paths is "Show full path on mouse hover". This is found under ( Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Editor Tabs )*

Answer (score 21):

The top bar should show you where your file is located:

[image]

Comment: I see now; it only shows the path relative to the project directory and the project directory is shown in the application window title.

Comment: However, when you open a file that is not in a project the application window title doesn't get updated.

Comment: @mattclegg Here on Windows (PhpStorm v7.1.2) navigation bar shows full path for outside-project files when that file is in focus: http://postimg.org/image/46m1rg1mr/

Comment: I just expected to it showing the path in the title bar of the application rather then in the toolbar. It can get a bit confusing when you open a file that is not in the current project (but has the same name as a file in the current project) http://postimg.org/image/3kx125v1f/

Comment: In the latest version you have to enable this yourself! -> `Settings | Apppearance & Behavior | Appearance | Always show full paths in window header`

Answer (score 9):

View > Appearance > check 'Navigation Bar'

Comment: Thanks! This is the solution for the hidden by default navigation bar in WebStorm 2022.1.4

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunatly the only option you have is for it to show the path for non-unique filenames.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

In new version 2023.2 right click in right conner of bottom panel and choose

```
Navigation Bar -> In status bar
```

Navigation Bar -> In status bar":
[image: Navigation Bar -> In status bar]

Comment: brilliant my IDE just became a little more minimalist

Answer (score 1):

You can also see the path and navigate the files using the Project tab (ALT + 1).

Answer (score 1):

At least from the current version of any JetBrains product:
For MacOS you can do `shift+option+cmd+C` - this will copy full path+line.

Answer (score 0):

A plugin called [Tabdir](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5045-tabdir) seems to do this reasonably well. From the plugin page:

> ... this plugin will allow you to have directory names added to tab labels. It only shows path differences so if you have "blog/controllers/index" and "news/controllers/index" it will add either [blog] or [news].

The plugin doesn't appear to have been updated since 2012, but is working on my Webstorm 2021.1.2 (screenshot below). When you have a large number of tabs open, an albeit unique `index` tab isn't particularly helpful...

[image]